# Sublime 3 Vintageous: Moving between "wrapped" lines instead of "real" lines

Tags: sublimetext3, word-wrap

I would like to know if is it possible in Sublime text 3 to change the behavior of the up and down movements to not jump to the next and previous "real" line but to the next and previous "visually wrapped" line. When I write code this is not an issue because I turn off the visual line folding (since my lines never go beyond the 80 characters). However when I am editing text for a Latex file, if I have a big paragraph that in reality is written within one "real" line, thanks to visual line wrapping, sublime displays it in 10 lines; Now the problem is that if I want to change something in the middle of these long paragraphs, I cannot use the up and down keys, they will only move me between real lines and not wrapped lines.

I've searched for an answer online to this problem of mine but I cannot find anything related anywhere

PS: I am actually using vintageous package, however I think that finding the solution for the  and  keys would be easier.

Comment: I just tested it and for me, it moves the cursor up one "visual line". I don't recall having changed any options about it

Comment: Hmmmm I just tested it now and the problem is given by the vintageous package. When I am in "insert mode" the movement works as I want, but when I am in the command mode it jumps between real lines.

I didn't realized this before since I rarely move in insert mode. I will try to find a solution for this in the github site of vintageous.

Comment: That's the `vim` way, so it's probably emulating it aswell. Why would anyone want to emulate vim on sublime text, that's over my head, but ok :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok after searching more and asking in the vintageous github I found that in `vim` the keys gj and gk do what I wanted to do.
The vintageous addon, as their [wiki](https://github.com/guillermooo/Vintageous/wiki/Configuration-File) says, support the maping of keys in the configuration file located in `Packages/User/.vintageousrc`.

All I needed to do to add the wanted behavior to the j and k keys was to edit that file and add:

`:map j gj`

`:map k gk`